# jvm startup error when adding jvm-option

Tags: java, glassfish, jvm, appdynamics

I downloaded Appdynamics agent for Java, which required adding jvm option for glassfish server 3.1.2, for javaagent.jar, giving path of agent. user which application server runs on has full permissions on this folder. After adding this jvm in glassfish server 3.1.2, a restart of server is required. After executing restart, server could not start givng error: error opening ZIP file or JAR manifest missing C:AppServerAgent:javaagent.rar. I noticed that the option was not added in domain.xml file, but still the option is required for starting the machine. I tried to add it manually in the domain.xml file, but still no success. What can I do? now the appication hosted by glassfish doesnt start because the server is down. 
Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of the entry you made in your domain.xml.

Comment: I added this jvm option, from glassfish admn console: -javaagent:C:\AppServerAgent\javaagent.jar

Comment: And also changed the osgi.properties file by adding : com.singularity.* to the org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation

Comment: I must note that after changes in the JVM options from the admin console, I checked the domain.xml file, and there were no changes in java-config jvm options. But still there is the error occurred during initialization of VM, agent library failed to init:instrument. Error opening ZIP file or JAR manifest missing:C:AppServerAgent:javaagent.jar

Answer (score 0):

The `asadmin` manual page says the following:

> For the Windows operating system in single mode, a backslash is
>   required to escape the colon and the backslash characters.

So try the following:

```
-javaagent:C\:\\AppServerAgent\\javaagent.jar
```

**See also:**

- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Administration Guide - Administering JVM Options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gepzd.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still no success. I also tried to put the path between quotes but still nothing. Have to say that this is not an asadmin command. it is JVM property. And also the administration guide is no use for me because it supposes that the server is up and running, while my glassfish instance does not start at all. The only changes I can make are changes to the domain.xml file.

Comment: You should edit that directly in the domain.xml. Does it give you the same error message?

Comment: Finally, I managed to start it. I changed it directly in the domain.xml file, but it was an old version I was changing. I just deleted the -javaagent jvm option and the instance started. I was editing an old backup of the domain.xml file. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You should accept the answer if you feel that it solved your problem (or post an alternative answer and accept that) to show that there is a solution for this problem.